# ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY not being captured

Tags: android, audio, headset

After reading the android dev-guide and some posts here, I have implemented a simple solution to capture a HEADSET UNPLUG event in my tablet running Android 2.3.3.

Unfortunately it seems I'm missing something since the onReceive() event never gets captured.

Bellow is the implemented code:

```
public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Headphones disconnected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


}
```

And in the android manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".MusicIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NOISY filter gets triggered when audio output sources change, and might cause funky stuff.

The correct filter for headset plug should be:

```
IntentFilter commandFilter = new IntentFilter();
commandFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
```

The Manifest should read:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Comment: The issue I'm running into with this is that it HEADSET_PLUG triggers on every onCreate of an Activity, so I'm getting a lot of false positives when I have no headphones plugged in.

Comment: You have to register on onResume and unregister on onPause

Comment: You don't need to register it in the Manifest unless you want the app to get launched when you plug in a headset.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG) says that you cannot register for this intent in the manifest. Additionally, this is only firing for wired headsets, and will not work with wireless ones. The ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY is sent out when a Bluetooth headset is disconnected, too.